# webpack-dev-server HMR not working, "hot-update" files fetched from the wrong port

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-hmr

I'm using HMR/livereload with webpack-dev-server on port 9000, but it's fetching update files from the webserver port. This causes it to force a full page reload. At the beginning of development, this was OK, but as the application has become more reliant on the state (it's a SPA) it really becomes annoying. But other bundled assets like fonts and images are loaded fine. Any help or hints would be appreciated!

[chrome network log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbxNS.png)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm having the same issue.